# How to create a View that shows flag fields and the number of times flagged per field

Tags: panels, views, flags

The idea is as follows:
I have a site where articles are evaluated with 7 labels. Authenticated users (not only the author) must be able to select a number of labels they want to apply to the article.

On the article page, there should be a views pane or block that lists the labels that have been applied to the article by everyone, and the number of times it has been applied.

[image]

I currently have the approach that I created 7 flags, and the views block needs 7 relations and 7 contextual filters which is a very inefficient way to display the flag count per flag.

Help is much appreciated